# Creating Dynamically Populating Spinners with Android

Tags: android, dynamic, spinner

I've been creating an Android Application for one of my Assignments and I have come across this problem. I am making a spinner that dynamically populates itself, however the application doesn't seem to open, and I cannot seem to find what the problem is. Any help or hints will be appreciated!

The Application basically creates sets when you press the button Create Set, and it would take the String entered in the EditText and would populate the spinner dynamically using the string taken from the EditText.

Basically my Activity Class looks like this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public final static String DISPLAY_MESSAGE = "com.android.setoperations.MESSAGE";
    private MySet mySet;
    private MySet set_list;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    this.mySet = new MySet();

    Spinner set_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.set_spinner);
    List<String> list = this.mySet.set_list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> setNamesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    set_spinner.setAdapter(setNamesAdapter);
}

public void createSet(View view){
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.element);
    String element = editText.getText().toString();

    this.mySet.createSet(element);
}
```

}

Furthermore, my spinner and button to save sets in main_activity.xml layout looks like this:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/set_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Create Set"
    android:onClick="createSet"/>
```

Lastly, my class for operations (MySet.java) look like this:

```
ArrayList<String> set_list = new ArrayList<String>();

public void createSet(String set_name){
    set_list.add(set_name);
}
```

Thank you! The Application would try to run then closes by itself and stops.

**Here is my logcat information:**

```
09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.setoperations/com.android.setoperations.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setAdapter(AbsSpinner.java:114)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(Spinner.java:382)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at com.android.setoperations.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)

09-21 20:08:18.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logcat would be helpful but I think the problem is here

```
 List<String> list = this.mySet.set_list;
```

You would get a `NPE` because you haven't yet iniitalized `mySet`

You don't do that until the next line after going to this method

```
    createSpinner();

    this.mySet = new MySet();
```

You need to initialize `mySet` before trying to call a method on it. So change the above lines around

```
    this.mySet = new MySet();
    createSpinner();
```

After looking a little more, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with

```
 List<String> list = this.mySet.set_list;
```

They are both instance variables of `MySet` besides neither are initialized

**Edit**

In your `onCreate()` you have

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
```

but the xml you posted you say is for `activity_main.xml` if that wasn't a typo in your post then the problem is trying to get a `View` from a `layout` which you haven't inflated.

Comment: Thank you for the input! I have tried changing it such that I initialize mySet before I call createSpinner, but it still seems to get a NPE. Logcat is saying that it is caused by a NPE. What set_list is, is a ArrayList which stores all the names of sets given by a user which was done in the operations class (MySet.java) I am trying to populate the spinner with the items in this.MySet.set_list.

Comment: Yes, see my edit. What you are doing doesn't seem to make sense. Also, if you could post your logcat into your question it would be mighty helpful ;)

Comment: What is at line 31 of `MainActivity`?

Comment: See my edit. Also, `createSpinner()` is a function not a class

Comment: my bad I meant function, i removed the createSpinner function and put it in onCreate. I fixed my code a little bit. The main_activity.xml is right I made a typo with the activity_main.xml!

Comment: Ok, see my edit to my answer. Also, please don't change code you have posted. You can edit and add the changes you have made but don't change the original. Also, you can use code formatting for logcat...easier to read

Comment: Thanks, your edit helped me out! I figured out why it was not working! Sorry about the trouble!

Comment: No trouble...that's what the site is for. I'm glad it's working.